# Using an awk script on multiple rows of a file

Tags: bash, unix, awk

I have the following file: (Not sure why it's not aligned here... It is in the terminal...)

```
Name        State   Pay Rate    Hours Worked    Overtime Hours  
John Doe    MO  13.75       27      0
Jane Doe    KS  21.00       32      0
Sam Smith   MO  32.50       40      8
Barb Jones  MO  28.25       40      16
Jenny Lind  KS  10.50       28      0
```

So I wrote this script:

```
#!/bin/awk -f

{
        name=$1" "$2
        state=$3
        payRate=$4
        hoursWorked=$5
        overtime=$6

        grossPay=(hoursWorked+(overtime*1.5))*payRate
        if (state == "KS")
                tax = grossPay* .07
        else if (state == "MO")
                tax = grossPay* .08
        else
                print "Tax info not found"

        netPay = grossPay-tax
}
END{
        print "Name    \tState\n",
        name, "\t", state,
        "\nGross Pay:\t$", grossPay,
        "\nTaxes:     \t$", tax,
        "\nNet Pay:\t$", netPay
}
```

Which produces the following:  (Not sure why there is a space before Jenny...)

```
Name        State
 Jenny Lind      KS 
Gross Pay:  $ 294 
Taxes:      $ 20.58 
Net Pay:    $ 273.42
```

My question is if there is a way to for loop through and use something like "FNR" to print the results of all of the different rows to print this same output for Barb Jones, Sam Smith, etc. stopping at Name.

Sorry if this is a dumb question

---

EDIT:

So I changed my script to:

```
#!/bin/awk -f

{
        name=$1" "$2
        state=$3
        payRate=$4
        hoursWorked=$5
        overtime=$6

        grossPay=(hoursWorked+(overtime*1.5))*payRate
        if (state == "KS")
                tax = grossPay* .07
        else if (state == "MO")
                tax = grossPay* .08
        else
                print ""

        netPay = grossPay-tax
        print "\nName    \tState\n",
        name, "\t", state,
        "\nGross Pay:\t$", grossPay,
        "\nTaxes:     \t$", tax,
        "\nNet Pay:\t$", netPay
}
END{
        print "\n-complete-"
}
```

and now get the output:

```
Name        State
 Name State      Pay 
Gross Pay:  $ 0 
Taxes:      $  
Net Pay:    $ 0

Name        State
 John Doe    MO 
Gross Pay:  $ 371.25 
Taxes:      $ 29.7 
Net Pay:    $ 341.55

Name        State
 Jane Doe    KS 
Gross Pay:  $ 672 
Taxes:      $ 47.04 
Net Pay:    $ 624.96

Name        State
 Sam Smith   MO 
Gross Pay:  $ 1690 
Taxes:      $ 135.2 
Net Pay:    $ 1554.8

Name        State
 Barb Jones      MO 
Gross Pay:  $ 1808 
Taxes:      $ 144.64 
Net Pay:    $ 1663.36

Name        State
 Jenny Lind      KS 
Gross Pay:  $ 294 
Taxes:      $ 20.58 
Net Pay:    $ 273.42
```

which is 95% what I need but how can I ignore the first line "name, state, etc." and I still can't figure out why it adds a space in front of the names.

Comment: `awk` by design loops through the lines of the file, you're only getting output once because you're only printing in your `END` block which is only executed once after all files are read.  In this case that means it will print the info for just the last line of the input.  Moving that outside of the END should help you out.
Also, (assuming you fix the end issue) the way this is configured right now if there is no tax info for someone, it will print out that error message above the output but then whatever the previous tax info is as the variable is not cleared.

Comment: Oh wow, I feel stupid... I put the END stuff in the body and it runs like I want. Thanks, btw is there an easy way for it to skip the first line? It outputs the "name, state, payrate, etc" line

Comment: I figured that'd be the next question.
Similar to BEGIN and END Block, `awk` allows you to specify other conditional blocks of code like `condition {executed if matches condition}`
So in this case, to skip the first line, you need to compare the NR field, e.g. `NR==1{next;}` before your main block.

Comment: ahhh ok so it's basically saying if record number is 1 go to the next line? That makes sense thanks. One more quick question, can you tell why it's adding a space before the names? I don't see why it would do that

Comment: Because the comma in the print is implying to print the OFS between those values. That is also why there is a space following your dollar signs.  Just use a space instead of a comma if you don't want anything between them. If you change the OFS to something obvious like xxx (e.g. `BEGIN {OFS="xxx"}`) it'd be easier for you to see this, if you don't understand what I mean.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot zzevann I actually learned a good amount from you just now, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some suggested improvements:

```
BEGIN {
    split("KS .07 MO .08",tmp)
    for (i=1;i in tmp;i+=2)
        taxRate[tmp[i]] = tmp[i+1]
    fmtS = "%12s%s\n"
    fmtF = "%12s$%.2f\n"
}
NR>1 {
    name=$1" "$2
    state=$3
    payRate=$4
    hoursWorked=$5
    overtime=$6

    grossPay=(hoursWorked+(overtime*1.5))*payRate
    tax = grossPay* taxRate[state]
    netPay = grossPay-tax

    printf fmtS, "Name", "State"
    printf fmtS, name, state
    printf fmtF, "Gross Pay:", grossPay
    printf fmtF, "Taxes:", tax
    printf fmtF, "Net Pay:", netPay
}
END {
    print "\n-complete-"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to zzevann here's my final code

```
#!/bin/awk -f

#Skips the first line
NR==1{next;}
{
        name=$1" "$2
        state=$3
        payRate=$4
        hoursWorked=$5
        overtime=$6

        grossPay=(hoursWorked+(overtime*1.5))*payRate
        if (state == "KS")
                tax = grossPay* .07
        else if (state == "MO")
                tax = grossPay* .08
        else
                tax = 0
                #If tax reads 0 you KNOW something's wrong

        netPay = grossPay-tax

        print "\nName     \tState"
        print name, "\t" state,
        "\nGross Pay:\t$" grossPay,
        "\nTaxes:     \t$" tax,
        "\nNet Pay:\t$" netPay
}
END{
        print "\n-complete-"
}
```

with the final output

```
Name        State
John Doe    MO 
Gross Pay:  $371.25 
Taxes:      $29.7 
Net Pay:    $341.55

Name        State
Jane Doe    KS 
Gross Pay:  $672 
Taxes:      $47.04 
Net Pay:    $624.96

Name        State
Sam Smith   MO 
Gross Pay:  $1690 
Taxes:      $135.2 
Net Pay:    $1554.8

Name        State
Barb Jones  MO 
Gross Pay:  $1808 
Taxes:      $144.64 
Net Pay:    $1663.36

Name        State
Jenny Lind  KS 
Gross Pay:  $294 
Taxes:      $20.58 
Net Pay:    $273.42
```